# Is it okay to access vector elements with an integer index?

Tags: c++

I have some integer variables and a vector. I need to use the integer variable as a index in the vector.

Is it okay to simply say `some_vector[some_integer]`?

Or do I need to somehow convert the integer to a size type?

Comment: All you need to do is make sure the index is valid for the container.

Comment: Yep, it's automatically converted to the vector's `size_type`

Comment: Did you even try?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, is will be converted to `size_t` without any warnings or errors. But beware of negative values. If your `int i` is negative, the conversion will yield `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() + 1 - abs(i)`, usually a very large number which is likely to lead to undesirable consequences. So if the index can be negative, check it before the indexing.

**UPD**:
Strictly speaking, there may be a warning depending on your compiler flags. In case of g++ there are two of them relevant here:

1. `-Wconversion` warns about conversions that may alter the value. In integer conversions this may occur when the destination type is smaller than the source (e.g. `int32_t y = 1000; int16_t x = y;`).
2. Signed-unsigned conversions where the destination is unsigned (e.g. `int16_t y = -1; uint32_t x = y;`) or the destination is of the same size as the source (e.g. `unsigned int y = UINT_MAX; int x = y;`) may change the value too, and in C `-Wconversion` does issue the warning, but in C++ you need to add `-Wsign-conversion` to make it appear.

I suspect they made the distinction in C++ precisely because people usually index `std::vector` using `int` and would have to make too much `static_cast`s to get rid of the warning if it appeared in this case.

Microsoft CL covers the first case by warning C4244, turned on by /W3 or /W4, and for the second case I could'n find a warning switch. If someone knows, please tell in a comment.

AFAIK, the C++ standard doesn't explicitly require `size_t` to be of equal size or larger than `int`. But I don't know any platform where it is not the case. So conversion from `int` to `size_t` falls into the second category.

To summarize: most likely, you will not receive a warning for `int` to `size_t` conversion in C++, as I stated before, unless you are using g++ with `-Wsign-conversion` switch.